# Can the enemy team see Kalista's "Oathsworn" link?

Tags: league-of-legends

When playing as Kalista, and using the Black Spear, a link is made. This link is visible between the two champions for the rest of the game when the two champions are close enough.

Is it visible to the enemy team, or only your own? For that matter, is it visible to the rest of your own team?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No,
Only Kalista and the champion you made your oathsworn can see te link

Comment: Yes, however you can see the link when Kalista activates her ultimate

Comment: Hey, had to be said =)

btw teammates can see the Oathsworn ally with a red circle by their feet

Answer (score 4):

No, your team is the only one that can see it.  But, while Kalista channels the ultimate, the enemy will be able to see the Oathsworn Bond.

Comment: This answer contradicts the other answer, which says that only the two involved players can see it. So which one is correct? Aside from that, how is it possible that they see it a second before you activate the ultimate? It's not like the game can predict that.

Comment: @RaimundKrämer Because the ult is a channel, and not instantly cast.  Edited the answer to reflect that.