# Is the enemy team able to see through the link?

Tags: league-of-legends

Skills like Taric's W or Kalista's passive, sends a link that connects allies.

According to the answers to this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/205631/can-the-enemy-team-see-kalistas-oathsworn-link), the enemies aren't able to see Kalista's Oathsworn

Can I assume that enemies can't see too in Taric's case?

Imagine that one of the champions is in lane and the other is in one bush, is the enemy team able to see the champion that is in the bush through the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Tethers are never visible to the enemy team.

Likewise ability telegraphs are not visible to the enemy team if they cannot see the player from whom the telegraph is sourced.

Example scenarios:

*Scenario: Taric is in the open, his ally is in the brush. Taric casts Bastion on his ally.*

The enemy can see Taric cast Bastion but cannot see on whom, nor any indicator as to its target's location.

*Scenario: Taric remains in the open, ally remains in brush. Taric casts Dazzle.*

The enemy again can see Taric channeling Dazzle and its associated telegraph; however they still cannot see Dazzle telegraphed from Taric's hidden ally.

To give a bit of back-end insight: If someone is hidden, they are hidden. No clientside data is provided for enemies currently invisible to a player; their whereabouts are completely unknown to your client application and so it is impossible for it to draw anything relating to that player or abilities cast by them.

Comment: Which is why Nidalee spears used to be invisible when fired from brush :)

Comment: Not quite as black and white as to the mechanics.  Like the comment above about Nidalee's spear, there's still Nunu's ult, Illaoi's hook that don't broadcast, but then there's Sol's stars, and so forth that do.  Also, Kalista's tether is visible to the enemy during her ult's channel.